# Flink yarn session job status switch to cancel after about 3 minutes

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have lunched a flink yarn session and these are the configuration of the cluster

```
akka.ask.timeout    100s
blob.server.port    30437
client.heartbeat.interval   300000
client.heartbeat.timeout    600000
execution.attached  false
execution.target    yarn-session
high-availability.cluster-id    yarn_id_xxxxxxxx
jobmanager.execution.failover-strategy  region
jobmanager.memory.heap.size 3462817376b
jobmanager.memory.jvm-metaspace.size    268435456b
jobmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.max  429496736b
jobmanager.memory.jvm-overhead.min  429496736b
jobmanager.memory.off-heap.size 134217728b
jobmanager.memory.process.size  4 gb
jobmanager.rpc.address  ip_xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx
jobmanager.rpc.port 29849
parallelism.default 1
slot.idle.timeout   600000
table.exec.sink.not-null-enforcer   drop
taskmanager.memory.managed.fraction 0.1
taskmanager.memory.process.size 4 gb
taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots   4
web.port    0
web.timeout 100000
web.tmpdir  /tmp/flink-web-fa91af25-b357-4dd1-85cd-d2d22687d241
```

My flink version is 1.17.1. After I submit a Streaming job to this session cluster, It will be canceled automatically after about 3min 50s. I have seen warn logs like

```
2023-11-20 10:49:48,888 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.dispatcher.StandaloneDispatcher     [] - The heartbeat from the job client is timeout and cancel the job 311ae90701dc4690098056064451684c. You can adjust the heartbeat interval by 'client.heartbeat.interval' and the timeout by 'client.heartbeat.timeout'
2023-11-20 10:49:48,890 DEBUG org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SharedSlot                [] - Cancel logical slot (SlotRequestId{6819b25041861c1f4057fcc2e281d630}) for execution vertex (id cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0) from the physical slot (SlotRequestId{5a697ec5179096c04937854b847ab0db}) from cbc357ccb763df2852fee8c4fc7d55f2_0
2023-11-20 10:49:48,890 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Job c9c26578e485cbedb34e283fcbb0a295:select * from my_kafka_table /*+ options('properties.group.id'='abcd', 'scan.startup.mode'='earliest-offset')*/ (311ae90701dc4690098056064451684c) switched from state RUNNING to CANCELLING.
2023-11-20 10:49:48,892 WARN  org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.CheckpointFailureManager [] - Failed to trigger or complete checkpoint 4 for job 311ae90701dc4690098056064451684c. (0 consecutive failed attempts so far)
```

As what it said, I increased client.heartbeat relate configuration but still make no sense.

It stuck me some days and I don't know how to fix it.